# Compare two strings and show if they are same with C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me please how to find if two texts are same, but if one of them is in one line and another is distributed over several lines!

In this case the result should be **TRUE**:

**Text 1:** "Compare two strings and show if they are same with C#"

**Text 2:** "Compare two strings and show

if they are same

with C#"

In this case the result should be **FALSE**:

**Text 1:** "Compare two strings and show if they are same with C#"

**Text 2:** "Compare two strings and do not show

if they are different

with C#"

Comment: please go through how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are the strings equal if there is not space after the word show?

Comment: @tymtam the strings are equal, but one of them is in more lines!

Comment: If you remove the new lines the string ends with  `if they are samewith C#` (please consider lack of space). Is the solution to consider that this is equal to `if they are same with C#` (with a space between same and with)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare `a.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"").Replace(" ", "")` with `b.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"").Replace(" ", "")`.

Test:

```
var a = "Compare two strings and show if they are same with C#";
// Please note that there are *no* spaces after "show" and "same"
var b = @"Compare two strings and show
if they are same
with C#";

Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(a, b, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));   // Gives -1
Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(
    a.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"").Replace(" ", ""), 
    b.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"").Replace(" ", ""),  
    StringComparison.InvariantCulture)); // Gives 0
```

Comment: This solution is not working, anyway, thanks :)

Comment: It works if you the spacing is preserved.

Comment: But the question was without spacing :\